# JPA: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo

Tags: java, jpa, javafx, jdbc

I get the following error after creating a Entity Class from a database and running the project. This error only shows up after creating the entity class and when I try to run the program in the MavenFXML project.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Bibliotekssystem: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo -> [Help 1]
```

I am new to JavaFX and JPA. This is what the project and code looks like with dependencies.

**pom.xml:**

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bibliotekssystem</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.bibliotekssystem.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="org.openjfx_Bibliotekssystem_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.openjfx.bibliotekssystem.Användare</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bibliotekssystem?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*******"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="*********"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*********"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2Nz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKgPx.png)

Comment: I'd say this might be a charset related issue. While I am a native speaker of a language with umlauts too, I'd never use them for class names for compatibly reasons. So try to change the name of the class from `Användare` to `Anvaendare` - this should probably work.

Comment: @maio290 Tried changing both entity name in database and java class name, unfortunately same error occurs.

Comment: Does adding the [Java EE API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/8.0) as dependency fix the problem?

Comment: @majo290 I get compilation errors after adding that dependency it says "module org.openjfx.bibliotekssystem reads package javax.persistence from both java.persistence and javaee.api", in module-info. Do I need to remove the persistence  dependency?

Comment: Nah, the Java EE API dependency was rather to test something. Basically, the `PersistenceUnitInfo` class should have been provided by the `javax.persistence` artifact. The [docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven) don't say anything about this dependency though.

Comment: @majo290 Hmm, yes you are right there is no PersistenceUnitInfo in my java.persistence package under my java.persistence jar. Can this be added?

Comment: It should be there - I just checked the jar file (downloaded from mvncentral) myself, it's contained in there. Could this just be a broken jar file in the end? oO

Comment: @maio290 Yes I did find it in the end, however I have solved this problem by deleting the module-info.java file in the project. I don't know why but it was causing problems. Thanks for the suggestions though.